# How to define a img tag inside a React.createElement() in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

Learning react and came across a scenario where I would want to define a 'img' tag inside React.createElement(). I have tried below syntax, but I am sure its a wrong method:

```
function Greeting() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Person />
      <Message />
    </div>
  );
}

const Person = () => {
  <h2>Its an Image</h2>;

  return React.createElement(
    "img",
    {},
    "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81l3rZK4lnL._AC_UL200_SR200,200_.jpg"
  );
};
```

The error which I get is as below:

```
Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
▶ 15 stack frames were collapsed.
Module.<anonymous>
E:/REACT_APP/tutorial/src/index.js:43
40 | return <p>Follow the white rabbit </p>;
41 | };
42 | 
> 43 | ReactDom.render(<Greeting />, document.getElementById("root"));
44 |
```

Please suggest,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arguments for `React.createElement` is as follows (as seen in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)):

> ```
> React.createElement(
>   type,
>   [props],
>   [...children]
> )
> ```

The last argument is the children, but when you create an image element, it should have no children (ie: it's a void element tag like the error mentions). Currently,  you're adding the image source as the children, giving equivalent to:

```
<img>
  https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81l3rZK4lnL._AC_UL200_SR200,200_.jpg
</img>
```

Instead, you need to specify the img source in the props of the created element, and pass `null` for the children (undefined/null would work here, so not supplying a 3<sup>rd</sup> argument will also work):

```
React.createElement(
  "img",
  {src: "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81l3rZK4lnL._AC_UL200_SR200,200_.jpg"},
  null
);
```

As a side note, the content that gets rendered is the content you *return* from your component. The `<h2>Its an Image</h2>;` isn't being returned or used anywhere, it's like writing `1 + 2` inside of a regular function, it will evaluate to `3`, but won't do much other than that unless you do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img2='https://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30600000/Bunny-bunny-rabbits-30657097-900-1350.jpg'



React.createElement("img", {src: img2, height: "200px",  width: "300px"}, null)
```